# In postgresql, how do you find aggregate base on time range

Tags: postgresql, time, range

For example, if I have a database table of transactions done over the counter. And I would like to search whether there was any time that was defined as extremely busy (Processed more than 10 transaction in the span of 10 minutes). How would I go about querying it? Could I aggregate based on time range and count the amount of transaction id within those ranges?

Adding example to clarify my input and desired output:

```
+----+--------------------+
| Id | register_timestamp |
+----+--------------------+
| 25 | 08:10:50           |
| 26 | 09:07:36           |
| 27 | 09:08:06           |
| 28 | 09:08:35           |
| 29 | 09:12:08           |
| 30 | 09:12:18           |
| 31 | 09:12:44           |
| 32 | 09:15:29           |
| 33 | 09:15:47           |
| 34 | 09:18:13           |
| 35 | 09:18:42           |
| 36 | 09:20:33           |
| 37 | 09:20:36           |
| 38 | 09:21:04           |
| 39 | 09:21:53           |
| 40 | 09:22:23           |
| 41 | 09:22:42           |
| 42 | 09:22:51           |
| 43 | 09:28:14           |
+----+--------------------+
```

Desired output would be something like:

```
+-------+----------+
| Count |   Min    |
+-------+----------+
|     1 | 08:10:50 |
|     3 | 09:07:36 |
|     7 | 09:12:08 |
|     8 | 09:20:33 |
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Show some sample data and what result you expect?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT time,
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS c, min(time) AS time
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY floor(extract(epoch from time)/600);
)
WHERE c > 10;
```

This will find all ten minute intervals for which more than ten transactions occurred within that interval. It assumes that the table is called `transactions` and that it has a column called `time` where the timestamp is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to redneb, I ended up with the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS c, min(register_timestamp) AS register_timestamp
FROM trak_participants_data
GROUP BY floor(extract(epoch from register_timestamp)/600)
order by register_timestamp
```

It works close enough for me to be able tell which time chunks are the most busiest for the counter.